# Do I need to call .Prepare?

Tags: vb.net, oracle, oracle11g, odp.net

Say I have the following code:

```
Using conn As New OracleConnection(connString)
    conn.Open()
    Using oCommand As New OracleCommand("MERGE INTO...")
        oCommand.BindByName = True
        oCommand.Parameters.Add("param1",OracleDbType.Raw,value,ParameterDirection.Input)
        oCommand.Parameters.Add("param2",OracleDbType.IntervalDS,value,ParameterDirection.Input)
        // etc.
        oCommand.Connection = conn
        oCommand.Prepare()
        oCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        oCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
End Using
```

Is the .Prepare necessary? What does it do in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, it's not required. According to the documentation of [IDbCommand.Prepare](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idbcommand.prepare(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The server automatically caches plans for reuse as necessary; therefore, there is no need to call this method directly in your client application.

Comment: Thanks, I missed that `OracleCommand` inherits from a class that implements `IDbCommand`, so the documentation for `IDbCommand` applies. If I wanted to do what they do in the example (i.e. run my sql multiple times with different parameters), would I then need the `Prepare` statement?

Comment: @simonalexander2005, been doing database programming since before dotNet, I have never called `Prepare`.

Comment: @simonalexander2005: You don't *need* it, although it *might* improve performance. Since the documentation is not very helpful in this regard, you'd probably have to do some tests (*if* this turns out to be a performance bottleneck in your application. If it isn't, don't worry about it and concentrate on those parts which *are* bottlenecks.)

Answer (score 0):

There's no benefit in calling OracleCommand.Prepare. It is a NOOP.

https://docs.oracle.com/html/E10927_01/OracleCommandClass.htm